# The coordinates of the plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I want to get the coordinates from 'barplot' function, but prohibit starting graphic device.

When I run followings,

```
x <- c(10, 23, 20)
y <- barplot(x)
```

the coordinates of 'barplot' are stored in y, and a bar plot appears simultaneously.
However, I don't want to start graphic device, what should I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is just an option of `barplot` as stated in the [help](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/barplot.html). You just have to do this:

```
y <- barplot(x, plot=FALSE)
```